# Is there way to copy data between tables in BigQuery with slightly different schemas in dynamic way?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have many tables with versions like these:
table_v1
table_v2
table_v3
...
table_vN

```
I want to run some code (could be whatever) which will do:
1) copy data from table_v1 to table_v2
2) copy data from table_v2 to table_v3
3) ...
4) copy data from table_vN-1 to table_vN
```

The main problem is that following schemas differ slightly and I don't want to adjust schemas or provide mocked columns with nulls for missing columns. I need to skip them in dynamic way.
Is there way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like (essentially defining proper target schema in query)

```
select t1.col1 as t2_col1, t1.col3 ad t2.col2... from table_v1
```

and set destination as table_v2 - and depends on what you means by copy (adding data or overwriting data) you use writeDisposition to define desirable outcome.

You can use [bq query command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_query) to do this or write script using BQ library for your language of choice. Or call BQ API [Query Job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query)

Comment: Thanks for answer but I want avoid listing columns ("defining proper target schema in query") as these are really complex, also what I want to achieve is automate this solution

Comment: I assume you have at least some mapping defined - so you have somewhere stored that table1.col1 = table2.col3. So in this case you could write simple python script that will build these queries for you. Relying on anything else to build mapping for you would be quite dangerous and impossible to debug